# What do you have in your log4net config? Hacks, optimizations, observations?

Tags: .net, optimization, logging, log4net

This is my log4net config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %5rms [%-17.17t] %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="MySmtpClientSmtpAppender">
    <to value="a@a.com" />
    <from value="admin@x.com" />
    <subject value="Game Server Monitoring Failed!" />
    <smtpHost value="smtp.x.com" />
    <username value="admin" />
    <password value="x" />
    <bufferSize value="256" />
    <lossy value="true" />
    <evaluator type="log4net.spi.LevelEvaluator">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </evaluator>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d [ThreadId: %t] Class:%c{1} Method:%M %nMESSAGE:%n%m%n%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs\\wwwlog" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <!--<rollingStyle value="Date" />-->
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
      <levelMin value="INFO" />
      <levelMax value="FATAL" />
    </filter>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>


  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="MySmtpAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Am I missing anything? Any tips/ advice to decrease log size while maintaining clarity, better conversion patterns? Any interesting hacks?

Edit: XMl file didnt get into the code block.Updating. Any sugggestions?

Comment: Highlight code, press Ctrl+K. Your html stopped it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One suggestion for the RollingLogFileAppender is to use the minimal lockingModel.  With this setting the log file isn't locked, rather it is opened and then closed for each write.

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

Comment: Good call. I use that too and it seems to help with my own log viewer so that it can browse the file as well.

Comment: `FileAppender.MinimalLock` is only necessary when you are trying to have multiple processes (note - processes, not threads; log4net is already thread safe) write to the same log file.  Otherwise it just slows things down: "This method of locking is considerably slower than FileAppender.ExclusiveLock", from http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock.html

Comment: I should also mention that multiple processes writing to the same log file is usually not a good idea.  From the [FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#single-file): "ask yourself whether you really need to have multiple processes log to the same file, then don't do it ;-)".  It's usually a better idea to give each process their own log file to write to.

Comment: @DanielSchilling It should be further added that `MinimalLock` is not enough if multiple processes are actually logging *simultaneously* to the same file. In this case, some writes will fail because the other process is writing / locking at the same time. This will cause an internal exception and the log entry will be lost. To solve this, you need an `InterProcessLock` which uses a mutex for coordination.

Answer (score 37):

Nobody mentioned encoding. It's pretty important if you are logging messages in Chinese, Japanese, Arabic or any double-byte language.
Here is an example:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <encoding value="utf-8" />
  <!-- etc. -->
</appender>
```

Comment: Very useful comment. I wish that it was the default. However, when using value="utf-8", all of the files will contain a BOM even if the file is empty. For typical logging, there is usually always content, so this is not an issue. However, this is undesirable for error and warning logs--which ideally should be empty--but will still show as 1 KB in size due to the BOM, so you always need to check it in case there really is an error in there. A work around is to use <encoding type="System.Text.UTF8Encoding" /> instead. This will omit the unneeded BOM, so the empty log will show up as 0 KB.

Comment: How to do with ConsoleAppender?

Answer (score 7):

For logging with diferent colors when showing on console depending on the message level (debug, info, error or fatal). The second appender is to save it on a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
     <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
   </configSections>

<log4net debug="false">
  <appender name="trace" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender, log4net">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

 <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender,log4net">
   <mapping>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <foreColor value="White" />
    <backColor value="Red" />
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <foreColor value="White" />
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <foreColor value="Green" />
  </mapping>

  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net" >
  <param name="File" value="Logs/NSCurrent.log" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <param name="RollingStyle" value="Date" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

  <root>
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
 </log4net>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 5):

To reduce log file size, you could try adjusting the ConversionPattern:

here's the format I use:

```
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
    <!-- a reduced format, saves bit of log space: -->
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date{MM/dd HH:mm:ss,fff}-{%level}-%message%newline"/>
  </layout>
```

BEFORE:

2012-06-05 10:58:40,819 [1] INFO  My App [(null)] - My App - ===star
ting....

AFTER:

06/05 11:17:29,151-{INFO}-My App - ===starting...

note: the documentation from Apache seems to be incorrect for log4net - as it says to use SSS for milliseconds, whereas log4net uses fff

A small saving per line could make a big difference overall :)

Answer (score 4):

I run a pretty minimal log4net configuration and prefer to use the XML format, but one thing I'd suggest adding (for web apps) is the ASP.NET trace appender. You simply have to add the following:

```
<appender name="AspNetTraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AspNetTraceAppender" >
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
</appender>
```

Then down at your root logger, or wherever you decide to activate it:

```
<root>
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="XmlSchemaFileAppender" />
   <appender-ref ref="AspNetTraceAppender" />
</root>
```

This allows me to get all of my pertinent debug data together on a single page when I'm debugging some minute ASP.NET details. Most of the time I have the ASP.NET trace appender commented out to disable it, but has really helped out in a few instances, especially when you're trying to figure out what particular server post back method is causing the hangup in your app.

Answer (score 2):

This may help a little, depending on how similar log4j and log4net are, I would think they are based on the same specification, but I don't know for sure.

Well I can't tell you what I have in my log4net config, but I can tell you what I have in my log4j config if that's good enough...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!--
    <appender name="CHAINSAW_APPENDER"
            class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender">
        <param name="RemoteHost" value="localhost" />
        <param name="Port" value="4445" />
        <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/>
        <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="10000"/>
    </appender>
    -->

    <appender name="FILE_APPENDER"
        class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="c:/dev/logs/OSB.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
         <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p [[[[%c]]]] (((%F:%L))) ___%C___ - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="WARN"/>
    </logger>

    <!--
    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.webapp.filter.GZIPFilte">
        <level value="WARN"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="BibleFormControllerTest">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.webapp.action.sample.jmesa.JMesaSampleController">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.webapp.action.binding">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.directwebremoting">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    -->

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.dao.hibernate">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.service.impl">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.service.dwr">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.conciliarpress.webapp.action">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>

    <root>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_APPENDER"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Also I have a corresponding chainsaw configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd"> 
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
   <plugin name="logFileReceiver" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LogFilePatternReceiver">
     <param name="fileURL" value="file:///c:/dev/logs/OSB.log" />
     <param name="timestampFormat" value="yyyy-MM-d HH:mm:ss,SSS"/> 
     <param name="logFormat" value="TIMESTAMP [THREAD] LEVEL [[[[LOGGER]]]] (((FILE:LINE))) ___CLASS___ - MESSAGE"/> 
     <param name="name" value="DLA_M_LogFile" />
     <param name="tailing" value="true" /> 
   </plugin>

   <root>
      <level value="debug"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Also here is some information that may help you decifer the latter file:
http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Configuring_a_log4j_RollingFileAppender_with_Chainsaw